# Android- method is permanently changing the value of variable

Tags: android, variables, methods

I have this method which I dont understand. 
2 global variables which are important for this questions:

-mNextButton;
-mCurrentIndex;

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

              mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

             int questionID = nameOfArray[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
            }
        });
```

how is it possible that mCurrentIndex is increased permanently every time user clicks mNextButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to be more specific. What do you really what to know? 
In your code you setup a callback, which will be called, when user press the button. Inside that code you updating your "global" variables (since java has no global variables, I will assume you mean class field variable inside activity)

`mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;`

this will update `mCurrentIndex` exactly as specific - it increase the index for one, and fold it, when the value increase more than `mQuestionBank.length`. % is a standard [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

For gaining more understanding check out your `mQuestionBank.length` parameter or write a better question. Good luck.

Comment: mQuestionBank is name of array. sorry.

i just want to know how is it possible for variable mCurrentIndex to change its value after the method  onClick is finished.
if it has value of 1 before method call, and method changes it to 2, shouldn't it again have value of 1 after the method is finished ?

Comment: Simple answer - no, it doesn't =) Let me try to explain, there are two types of variables - locals and globals. locals - it's a variable you define inside some function. they will be created during your method execution and after that - they will be gone. global variable - the different one. for example class field variables. they created when you create your class instance and then if at some method you change their values - this changes will be still there after the method executed. I recommend you read some basic book about java or any other programming language.

Comment: To try and help clear this up, because you are using a variable (`mCurrentIndex`) created _outside_ of your function, it will continue to exist and have the same value. If your variable was created inside of your function, it would be created every time that `onClick()` is called

Answer (score 0):

For solving this you need to set one local variable. So in your onClick method:-

```
int mCIndex = mCurrentIndex;

mCIndex = (mCIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;



   int questionID = nameOfArray[mCIndex].getQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question

);
```

Thats it

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, but thats not what I am looking for as the code I posted is fine. mQuestionBank is name of array, and every time user clicks the mNextButton, mCurrentIndex is changed

Comment: Then what is the issue. Is it that mCurrentIndex alway increases at same rate ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of mCurrentIndex is set to the value of

```
(mCurrentIndex+1) % mQuestionBank.length
```

with every click on mNextButton.
This value is depending on the mCurrentIndex and the length of mQuestionBank. To explain the operation, take a look at the modulo operator:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

To cut it short:
If mCurrentIndex for example has a value of 4, it's incremented by 1 and you get 5. 
Now, it's depending on the length of your mQuestionBank. If it's 2000 it will have 0-1999 residual classes. Every number that you modulo by 2000 will fall into one of these classes. 
So if you do the operation 0 mod 2000 equals 0, because 0 divided by 2000 has no remainder.
1 mod 2000 is 1 because 1 divided by 2000 is 0 with a remainder of 1. And 5 mod 2000 will be equal to 5.
In your case: mCurrentIndex will increase with every click until

```
mCurrentIndex+1 = mQuestionBank.lenght
```

because then it will start with 0 again. Since, in this example, 2000 mod 2000 is 1 with no remainder.